What's the counterpart to "spheroid" for a circle? There's no "circoid"
I'd like to know for the word for a deformed circle. Considering the prevalence of "spheroid", I'm amazed that I've been unable to locate an equivalent for a circle.
I realize that, theoretically, nothing except a circle is a circle. However, the existence of "spheroid" demonstrates that there is a use for describing something as its closed standard form. Consequently, what is the counterpart to "spheroid" that applies to a circle?

Or maybe the more vague "round"

@WGroleau, that tends to imply regularity, even if its definition doesn't explicitly define it as such.

I guess "spheroid" is more useful because a nearly-spherical ellipsoid is a good approximation to the shape of the Earth, whereas we seldom need a word for a nearly-circular ellipse.

I think part of the confusion is that there’s an inconsistency in how these objects are named: “spheroid” uses “-oid” to mean “sort-of-a-sphere”, whereas “ellipsoid” is something like “elliptically generated spheroid” rather than “sort-of-an-ellipse”

The "oid" suffix usually means "like" or "resembling", but the word circloid is already used for a more specific type of cycloid. There are many examples of specific words for round shapes in particular contexts, such as rondelles, biscuits, blots, etc. but I don't think there's any English word that specifically means an imperfect circular shape in general.

An oval is a plane figure sometimes defined as egg-shaped or like a stretched or deformed circle. Wikipedia says that in geometry "generally, to be called an oval, a plane curve should resemble the outline of an egg or an ellipse", although in sports tracks an oval track often has straight sides and rounded ends.
An ellipse resembles a squashed circle with two axes of symmetry, such as the orbit of a body around a point, and is more precisely defined.

Thanks. I feel a little stupid now.

ovoid is more general than "oval" or "elliptic" to describe "deformed circles".

@Graffito Nope. Ovoid is the 3D version of oval. Never 2D. The adjective for both is ovate, which is a bit confusing.

Ellipse is the 2D equivalent to the 3D ellipsoid, but spheroids are not necessarily ellipsoids, according to the definition as well as to the examples. A casual adjective might be round-ish, but I don't know of a noun for an "approximately round" 2D shape.

@PhilSweet : The suffix "oid" is added to mean resembling; having the likeness of (usually including the concept of not being the same despite the likeness).

Spheroids are 3D closed quadratic surfaces. In 2D, that leaves only the ellipse, of which a circle is one example.
For an oval, the 3D equivalent is ovoid. (And the adjective ovate is used for both.)
I'm sure that for many, "quadratic surface" doesn't help much with being able to recognize what is and isn't a spheroid or ellipse, which is why these tend to be used idiomatically and rather loosely by the public, along with all the other names for the quadratic shapes.

Thank you. That explains a lot.

I couldn't tell whether he wanted a noun or an adjective, like roundish or circular.

@tchrist, if you mean me (the OP) then I'm looking for a noun. I should have included articles in my title, in retrospect.
